# Is Prince Charming a Charming or a Fortuna?

Tags: shrek

In *Shrek 2*, Shrek looks through Fiona’s diary and flicks through pages that say:

> Mrs Fiona Charming

However, The Fairy Godmother‘s is named in one of the deleted scenes from Shrek 1 as "Dama Fortuna", which would seem to make 'Fortuna' Charming’s surname.

**So if Fiona married Charming, she would be Fiona Fortuna. Is that right?**

Comment: I’ve edited the title to match your actual question more closely but kept the body basically the same.

Comment: I don't know how reliable the Shrek wiki is but apparantly [Dama Fortuna, means "Dame Fortune" or "Lady Luck"](http://shrek.wikia.com/wiki/Fairy_Godmother) so that could just mean title firstname combo.

Comment: @sumelic - Not only is there no evidence that Dama Fortuna is a forename/surname combination, there's zero canonical evidence that that's her name at all. It only appears in the (deleted) storyboard sequence for Shrek 1

Comment: For your information, @NicolaTalbot, I added that Lady Luck information on the Shrek Wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prince Charming's *forename* appears to be Charming (in the same way that you might refer to Princess Fiona or Prince Charles). His family name and the name of his father haven't been revealed in the film or supplementary materials.

---

While we're on the subject of names you might wish to note that the Fairy Godmother's *character name* is explicitly stated to be

> "[The] Fairy Godmother"

[image]

The only place the name 'Dama Fortuna' appears is in a [deleted storyboard sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLwINMsqvjA&feature=youtu.be&t=13s) from the opening of the first Shrek film, in which her part was entirely deleted. As such, it's not clear that this is actually her given name, a title or simply a broad description of her role in the prologue, any more than Fiona's real name is "monster" or  Farquaad's name is "regent".

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I have no information, only speculation.

I give several completely arbitrary personal names to members of the family.

Possible Prince Charming's full name and title is Robert Fortuna, Prince Charming.  That is, a man named Robert Fortuna, with the title of Prince Charming.

Or perhaps the Fairy Godmother's maiden name was Mary Fortuna, hereditary Dama (lady of) Fortuna, and she married Albert Charming, Prince (of) Charming, and became Princess of Charming.  When her husband Prince Albert deed she became the dowager Princess of Charming, and her son Robert became the Prince of Charming.

So then the full title of Mary Fortuna Charming would be Dama Fortuna and dowager Princess of Charming.

And maybe in the world of *Shrek 2* it isn't customary to refer to widowed noblewomen by dowager titles, so the Fairy Godmother was only called Dama Fortuna, her hereditary title, and not by the title of her deceased husband.

But that doesn't explain why Fiona would daydream about being "Mrs. Fiona Charming" instead of "Fiona, Princess Charming" or "Princess Fiona of Charming".  It is possible that in the world of *Shrek 2* not all wives of princes get the title of princess.

Perhaps wives of low rank in the world of *Shrek 2* have to be content with "morganatic" or unequal marriages and do not get their husband's title but might possibly be granted some lesser title for themselves and their children.  That was the case among European royalty and nobility from about 1450 to the present, through the rule has been relaxed in the last few decades.

Of course Fiona was the daughter of the King and Queen of Far, Far, Away, but she was also sometimes in the form of an ogre, and might have believed that would make her considered a member of a lower species and thus not eligible for an equal marriage with Prince Charming.

So maybe Fiona daydreamed of becoming the wife of Prince Charming without expecting that she would automatically be made his princess

Comment: Well, many people call the Fairy Godmother Dama Fortuna and as such, one fan fiction page I read called Prince Charming Charming Fortuna.

Comment: @AlexDowns - I could go write a fan fiction right now and name him Charming Vader and it would be just as legitimate. There is no reason to cite fan fiction as evidence